# How to Get the Auth Token of Skype using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, cookies, oauth, httpurlconnection, skype

I'm trying to login to my user in Skype using HttpURLConnection class in JAVA. My objective is to get the Auth token(Which expires every 24hours) for my user. I'm following the Request cookies that are being sent in every HTTP call and sending the same set of cookies in JAVA program. But when response is received, there is a difference in the cookies received by the HTTP call made when I login through browser and HttpURLConnection class.

Can anyone help on this?

```
/**
 * Created by shreyas on 23/09/15.
 */

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


public class HttpsURLConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String httpsURL = "https://login.skype.com/login?client_id=578134&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.skype.com&intsrc=client-_-webapp-_-production-_-go-signin&message=logged_out&lc=16393";

        String query = "username="+URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8");
        query += "&";
        query += "password="+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8") ;
        String cookies = "MSFPC=ID=7257d650ce6da54f8f16951c796b637f&CS=3&LV=201508&V=1; SWACC=TM=1442036652; tracking=1443005674353; mbox=PC#1441957179127-901122.28_13#1445597676|session#1443005606468-117694#1443007536|check#true#1443005736; frmrgtpe=1-3; lastLogin=SK; skype-session=5a490f691979c9d9cfc9b592d8efe2b3828feb29; skype-session-token=ed386369f29ac162d028d11fe4d6f365b462ba1c; SC=CC=:CCY=EUR:ENV=:LC=en:LIM=:RS=m:TM=1444300641:TS=1444300641:TZ=:UCP=:VAT=:VER=; s_vi=[CS]v1|2AEE1E5585489697-60000103A002F05F[CE]; s_pers=%20s_fid%3D47DE135BD66B6E10-3A8420CADAC57A3E%7C1507459045330%3B%20gpv_p23%3Dskypeloginweb%252Faccount%252Flogin%7C1444302445338%3B%20s_nr%3D1444300645341-Repeat%7C1507372645341%3B; s_sess=%20s_ria%3Dflash%252019%257C%3B%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B";
//        String payload="{\"username\":\"username\",\"method\":\"UnifiedMVP2\", \"password\":\"password\", \"timezone_field\":\"+05|30\", \"js_time\":\"1444029538.658\", \"session_token\":\"448f4256096509ca35740235e7b78f3306156c97\", \"client_id\":\"578134\", \"redirect_uri\":\"https://web.skype.com\", \"pie\":\"7iw9lnVzLBaE3pIAFTD+Wn6rY17lkifj+9rXTt8LAFcMaex++atApZ6r404safgR8cxliXnLP3PF2Gqd9HKwjzA2NDIzNTI5M2I0YjliZTMxYWE1NjYzMWYwNjRmNzdh\", \"etm\":\"+oMsu5T+fvyJC89yhfDfhduvhoAx2RzS84mqD43PNz5sepudpPTo2KLGoKXEei7Ee9gpvgZj2W2H/Uc+O+f8oDkyZTJlZDAyOTg4NDExM2QxNzllZmU4NjkyOTFjMmU4\"                   }";

        URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        con.setRequestProperty("Cookies",cookies);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length()));
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www- form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)");
//        con.connect();

        con.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        output.writeBytes(query);
    //    output.writeBytes(payload);
        output.close();

        try{
            con.setDoInput(true);
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e){
            System.out.print("\nIllegal State Exception \n"+e);
        }

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( con.getInputStream() );
            for( int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read() )
                System.out.print( (char)c );
            input.close();




        System.out.println("Response Code :"+con.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Response Message  :"+ con.getResponseMessage());

        Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = con.getHeaderFields();
        Set<String> headerFieldsSet = headerFields.keySet();
        Iterator<String> hearerFieldsIter = headerFieldsSet.iterator();

        while (hearerFieldsIter.hasNext()) {
            String headerFieldKey = hearerFieldsIter.next();
            if ("Set-Cookie".equalsIgnoreCase(headerFieldKey)) {
                List<String> headerFieldValue = headerFields.get(headerFieldKey);
                int n= headerFieldValue.size();
                System.out.println("Number of cookies="+n);

                for (String headerValue : headerFieldValue) {
                    System.out.println("Cookie Found...");
                    String[] fields = headerValue.split(";\r*|;\n*|;\t*|;\f*");
                    //System.out.println("header Value="+headerValue);
                    String cookieValue = fields[0];
                    String expires = null;
                    String path = null;
                    String domain = null;
                    boolean secure = false;
                    // Parse each field

                    for (int j = 1; j < fields.length; j++) {

                        if ("secure".equalsIgnoreCase(fields[j])) {

                            secure = true;

                        }

                        else if (fields[j].indexOf('=') > 0) {

                            String[] f = fields[j].split("=");

                            if ("expires".equalsIgnoreCase(f[0])) {

                                expires = f[1];

                            }

                            else if ("domain".equalsIgnoreCase(f[0])) {

                                domain = f[1];

                            }

                            else if ("path".equalsIgnoreCase(f[0])) {

                                path = f[1];

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    System.out.println("cookieValue:" + cookieValue);
                    System.out.println("expires:" + expires);
                    System.out.println("path:" + path);
                    System.out.println("domain:" + domain);
                    System.out.println("secure:" + secure);
                    System.out.println("*****************************************");

                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println("Response Code :"+con.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Response Message  :"+ con.getResponseMessage());









    }



}
```

Comment: "application/x-www- form-urlencoded" - definitely has an extra space before "form" that would break content type.